# Prediction Model to predict when the future events will happen next month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, prediction

I have to develop a Prediction Model using Python to predict if a site will crash next month or not depending on the occurances in the last 6 monthes. Input Parameters are: `Environment(Dev,Prod,Test)`, `Region(NA,APAC,EMEA)` and the Date of the month.

I am using matplotlib, pandas and numpy. It will be a 2D Data Frame or a 3D Panel in Pandas. I am not sure as input parameters are 3 - `Region`, `Env` and Date.
I think below Machine Learning Algorithm should be used:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Linear regression can be used if all the assumptions of L.R. is satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

Linear regression is fine, but calling it is just two line of work, i would suggest try multiple machine learning algorithms, tuning their hyperparameters and checking which gives the best performance, moreover you should look into feature engineering, maybe you could extract features from the already given data